# Second-rate spelling

Tags: word, no-computers, english, open-ended

Find the **longest word** which can be spelled with the **second letters** of a group words in **alphabetical order**. An example with `incomprehensible` (16 letters):

> a`i`m
>   a`n`swer
>   e`c`centric
>   f`o`ld
>   i`m`plore
>   i`p`silateral
>   i`r`idium
>   j`e`ster
>   k`h`aki
>   l`e`g
>   o`n`e
>   o`s`trich
>   p`i`g
>   u`b`iquitous
>   u`l`terior
>   v`e`ndetta

In the case of a tie, the winner is the solution whose last word (here, `vendetta`) comes first in alphabetical order.

Checking a dictionary for words (online or offline) is fine, but no programming or other automated solutions. May the best human win!

**Notes** (added after several answers):

> - No acronyms or abbreviations
> - No proper names

Comment: Inspired by @SlowMagic's recent "human-only" puzzles :)

Comment: Are abbreviations allowed? E.g., USA, CPU, GCD?

Comment: @bazzilic No abbreviations. Otherwise you could make literally any two-letter combination usin one abbreviation or another...

Comment: Isn't this puzzle just a re-phrase of the question "Find as many english words as possible to get a full set of letters (A-Z) from the 2nd character of each word?"  And from there on finding the longest existing English word? I feel that this challenge would be much more fun if the built word would have to describe the set of words used to build it.

Comment: @BmyGuest The challenge is the requirement that the list of words be in alphabetical order.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [open-ended puzzles are off-topic](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6617/the-end-of-open-ended-puzzles) as of May 2019

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if this counts:

### 27 letters - [Honorificabilitudinitatibus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorificabilitudinitatibus)

> `a h old`
> `a o rta`
> `c n ida`
> `c o ral`
> `c r ane`
> `d i ce`
> `e f fect`
> `e i ght`
> `i c e`
> `j a b`
> `k b ar`
> `k i ss`
> `k l oof`
> `l i ttle`
> `n t h`
> `n u ll`
> `o d e`
> `o i ntment`
> `o n`
> `p i tt`
> `p t erodactyl`
> `q a t`
> `s t able`
> `t i me`
> `u b iquitous`
> `v u g`
> `y s laked`

NOTE: The above is rejected I believe mainly because of kbar - short for kilobar. `nth` is in [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nth) while `zth` [is not](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zth).

---

Note sure if this works either

### 27 letters - [chemolithoheterotrophically](https://ijs.microbiologyresearch.org/content/journal/ijsem/10.1099/00207713-51-4-1463)

> `a c e`
> `a h old`
> `b e`
> `e m erge`
> `e o n`
> `f l y`
> `g i st`
> `i t erate`
> `k h aki`
> `k o ala`
> `m h o`
> `n e mesis`
> `n t h`
> `o e uvre`
> `o r ganism`
> `p o rt`
> `p t erodactyl`
> `s r addha`
> `t o p`
> `u p`
> `w h o`
> `w i tch`
> `y c lad`
> `z a p`
> `z l oty`
> `z l otys`
> `z y gote`

Comment: Pretty good! I have some reservations about yslaked (see comments to Omega Krypton's answer). I think nth is fine as it's certainly a word that's in common usage, even though it opens up something of a slippery slope (what about zth? etc). Note that I've added a rule (after your answer) which disallows abbreviations, so unfortunately kbar doesn't count...

Comment: @jafe Aw, ok, no prob, I'll probably have to give it another go. I was using this online [anagrammer](https://www.anagrammer.com/scrabble/yslaked) and found it there, so at the time I thought it would work. Back to the think tank I guess!

Comment: This is currently the leading answer. I'm going to allow yclad (and similar words) since they can be found in multiple English-language dictionaries (albeit often marked "archaic") and [are accepted in Scrabble](https://scrabble.hasbro.com/en-us/tools#dictionary).

Answer (score 14):

### 25 - antidisestablishmentarian

> a**a**rdvark
> a**n**timony
> a**t**tune
> b**i**sect
> e**d**ict
> e**i**genvector
> e**s**ter
> f**e**stive
> i**s**sue
> i**t**erate
> j**a**ckanapes
> o**b**elisk
> o**l**igarchy
> p**i**cnic
> p**s**alm
> r**h**eumatism
> s**m**elly
> t**e**ndency
> u**n**savory
> u**t**ilitarian
> v**a**ried
> v**r**oom
> w**i**tness
> x**a**nthan
> y**n**ambu

Comment: now do pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis

Comment: @AHKieran It turns out that's not possible!  If you break the word into alphabetical runs you get 25 distinct chunks, the last two of which are 
"ios" and "is".  No words start with "zs" (for the last letter), so "is" have to belong to y.  This means you need "xi-", "xo-" and "xs-" words, the last of which doesn't exist

Comment: (Notice that this isn't even "antidisestablishmentarianism", which for similar reasons doesn't appear to be possible.)

Comment: @Rubio "Antidisestablishmentarianism" only has 13 alphabetical chunks, which gives you a *lot* more flexibility.  I'll take your word for it, but I find that pretty surprising

Answer (score 8):

I believe I can get

> antidisestablishmentarian

using the following...

> a a rdvark 
>  a n t 
>  a t e 
>  b i d 
>  e d ucate 
>  e i ght 
>  e s sence 
>  f e et 
>  i s 
>  i t 
>  l a boratory 
>  o b lique 
>  o l factory 
>  p i glet 
>  p s oriasis 
>  r h ododendron 
>  s m all 
>  t e nacious 
>  u n wise 
>  u t most 
>  v a riable 
>  v r oom 
>  w i nner 
>  x a nthophyll 
>  y n ambu

Comment: did you just comment-snipe me? lol

Comment: @Rubio I'm so sorry, I did not see your answer or your comment before I had finished mine! I guess great minds think alike...?

Comment: Clearly :) Nice find. My comment, your answer, and my answer were all within like 4 minutes (and in that order).

Answer (score 7):

Here's an 18:

> INCONSEQUENTIALITY:
>  a**i**miable
>  a**n**gina
>  e**c**ological
>  e**o**silophilia
>  g**n**at
>  i**s**chaemic
>  j**e**tstream
>  o**q**uassa
>  o**u**trageous
>  p**e**rsimmon
>  p**n**eumatic
>  p**t**armigan
>  q**i**
>  r**a**ndom
>  s**l**aughterhouse
>  t**i**tanium
>  u**t**erus
>  z**y**gote

And a 20:

> UNCHARACTERISTICALLY:
>  a**u**thoritarian
>  c**n**idarian
>  e**c**hidna
>  e**h**
>  f**a**miliar
>  f**r**aught
>  g**a**stronomic
>  i**c**icle
>  i**t**erative
>  j**e**remiad
>  k**r**ypton
>  m**i**smanagement
>  o**s**culation
>  o**t**iose
>  p**i**gheadedness
>  s**c**andium
>  t**a**rtrate
>  u**l**lage
>  u**l**timate
>  z**y**murgy

And a 23: (Oops, no, there was an error in this one, pointed out by Rubio in TSL. Since I now have a longer one I shan't bother trying to fix it.

And a 24:

> TETRAIODOPHENOLPHTHALEIN:
>  a**t**ropine
>  b**e**lladonna
>  c**t**enoid
>  d**r**agoon
>  e**a**rldom
>  e**i**genvalue
>  e**o**lithic
>  i**d**empotent
>  i**o**nization
>  i**p**ecac
>  k**h**azi
>  l**e**ucocyte
>  m**n**emonic
>  m**o**lybdenum
>  o**l**factory
>  o**p**position
>  p**h**enolphthalein
>  p**t**erodactyl
>  r**h**esus
>  s**a**rcophagus
>  s**l**atternly
>  t**e**leological
>  t**i**mber
>  u**n**imodal

The dictionary file on my computer has no words longer than that other than "antidisestablishmentarianism", which I think *can't* be done -- but of course it isn't exhaustive...

Comment: I got to the 24th letter of antidisestablishmentarianism with "xanthan, but I couldn't make it further.

Comment: Yeah, I can get that far but no further.

Comment: I get through antidisestablishmentarian (25) with ynambu, but I had to scan the dictionary to find that one.

Comment: Scanning the dictionary is explicitly permitted. Go ahead and post your winning answer!

Comment: @Rubio if you want to post yours, I can delete mine -- I just saw this after posting!

Comment: Can you include the full words somewhere? It's hard to read them in this format.

Comment: @THiebert Done.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a...

### 30 - pseudopseudohypoparathyroidism

> a p e 
> a s ide
> b e come
> b u t
> e d ible
> e o n
> e p ilogue
> e s pecially
> f e ed
> f u el
> i d ol
> i o n
> k h an
> k y ar
> m p ret
> n o tice
> o p posite
> p a rt
> p r ey
> q a di
> s t and 
> t h at
> t y rant 
> u r anium
> w o men 
> x i phoid
> y d rad
> y i eld
> y s laked 
> z m uda :( Sad to hear about the note...

Comment: Nice work! I wonder about ydrad and yslaked. Are those still valid English? At least in Wiktionary they're marked as "obsolete" forms. I've never heard of either word, but then again the same goes for many other words in these solutions which are still perfectly valid :P

Comment: Impressive! I can't find any hits for zmuda, which I was curious about though? Is that a real word? I only found it as a name

Comment: Hi @Jerry thank you for you question. I believe an American surname would suffice as an English word?

Comment: and may I know the reason why this was downvoted? thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if surnames are allowed? I guess it'll be better if @jafe could confirm that.

Comment: I'll make a note disallowing proper names. I think we could throw the "english" tag out of the window if we allow constructing the answers from words like Mkrttchian (yes, that's an actual surname)...